# python selenium how to get certain text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

Is this possible in selenium, 
I think it's possible in urllib but I'm not sure.

```
if "@gmail.com" in html:
print the string that includes the @gmail
```

> ex: it will find `@gmail.com`, then it will print the string that is >connected too it `stackoverflow@gmail.com`

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315533/can-i-find-an-element-using-regex-with-python-and-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can request the entire HTML of a page using `page_source`. Then you can check if `@gmail.com` is in this `page_source`.

```
source = driver.page_source
domain = '@gmail.com'
if domain in source:
    # Cut off the string behind @gmail.com (the mail is now the last word in the string)
    sub = source[:source.find(domain) + len(domain)]
    # Get the last space and get the substring that comes after it
    mail = sub[sub.rindex(' ') + 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. What you want to achieve is:

1. look through the entire HTML document for any `@gmail.com`,
2. If there is a match, find out the whole email address.

What you can do is basically:

1. `entireDocument = findElement(By.xpath("/html"))`, this xpath will give you the entire html document stored in `entireDocument` variable.
2. then you can use regular expression to look for string `@gmail.com` within `entireDocument` and extract the whole email address if there is a match.