# Python Selenium - Find element whose class name starts with something

Tags: python, css, class, selenium, css-selectors

How can I retreive an element whose class name starts with, let's say: "PP-".
I tried this without success:

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class^='PP-']")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I find an element using regex with Python and Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315533/can-i-find-an-element-using-regex-with-python-and-selenium)

Comment: With xpath -> `//div[starts-with(@class, 'PP-')]`. I find it more straighforward than the CSS selector syntax.

Comment: That should work, are you sure the entire class attribute starts with `'PP-'` and it isn't something more like `'anotherclass PP-foo'` ?