# How can I get SVG chart data with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, charts, popup

Is it possible to get the value that can be seen in the pop-up appearing when moving the mouse left-right over this [chart](https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/ES*0/interactive-chart)?

If I can see it I guess I can scrape it, but I struggle to find the source of the data fed into the chart, neither the pop-up.
I can only find the rectangles of the SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible, by using the aria-label as an xpath, as well as regex to match by unique words such as 'high' or 'open', you could then extract the information you would like, that's also present in the popup :) If you hover over the chart with developer tools > inspect, you'll see the below example

```
184. Monday, Dec  3, 2018. category, 1543795200000. y, 2804. open, 2800. high, 2826.75. low, 2787. close, 2804.
```

more information on using regex with xpath: 
[Can I find an element using regex with Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315533/can-i-find-an-element-using-regex-with-python-and-selenium)