# how to get the src attribute of a LinkedIn multiple profiles using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, linkedin-api

Python code

`sign_in_button1=driver.find_element_by_xpath('''/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/img''')`
`src = sign_in_button1.get_attribute('src')`
`print(src)`

I am trying to retrieve the src attribute of LinkedIn users just by putting their LinkedIn profile URL, The problem is that I do not want to use find_element_by_xpath, because of this I have to constantly change the XPath for different profiles which make is it too tedious and unconventional. Please suggest me how can I make it dynamic
For eg: As soon as I put the LinkedIn URL I get the respective src attribute of the image

Comment: Can you pls give an example of the URL's ?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you need to extract? Is it profile pictures from all the profile URL's?

Comment: I noticed that all profile `img` tag has the id `'ember' + number`. Where number can be any integer. So you can get the img tag using such relation. This SO question will help you to do it. Hope I helped :). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315533/can-i-find-an-element-using-regex-with-python-and-selenium/46940945

Comment: @rootkonda https://www.linkedin.com/in/gaurav-aswani-ga009/

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian I am trying to extract profile images using LinkedIn profile. So as soon as the user puts WEB URL the image should popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class name that contains the same phrase:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains("@class, 'presence-entity__image presence- 
entity__image')]")
```

And then you can retrieve the src as you did.