# Python : Regular expressions in xpaths using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I try to get the id of certain HTML tags using Python and Selenium.
There is html code:

```
<tr id="10">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div class="card-view">       
            <span class="value">PROVIDER_628_54678931</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="11">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div class="card-view">       
            <span class="value">PROVIDER_629_54678932</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr id="12">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div class="card-view">       
            <span class="value">PROVIDER_730_54678933</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr id="13">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div class="card-view">       
            <span class="value">PROVIDER_6542_54678934</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

For extract id of only one parent tag i do :

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'value') and text()='PROVIDER_628_54678931']")
parent = elem.find_element_by_xpath('../../..')
print(parent.get_attribute("id"))
```

How to use regex in XPath to get parent id-s of "span" element where the text contains "PROVIDER_6XX", but not "PROVIDER_7" and PROVIDER_6542?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315533/can-i-find-an-element-using-regex-with-python-and-selenium)

```
def findTrunksByRegExp():
    pattern = re.compile(r"PROVIDER_6\d{2}")
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'value')]")
    for element in elements:
        match = pattern.match(element.text)
        if match:
            parent = element.find_element_by_xpath('../../..')
            print(parent.get_attribute("id"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I will use `contains`:

```
//span[contains(text(),'PROVIDER_6') and contains(@class, 'value')]
```

Comment: Also `starts-with(text(),'PROVIDER_6')` can be an option

Comment: Thanks, Wasif Hasan and JaSON. But i need solution using regexp. I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

XPath 2.0 supports regex, but Selenium support XPath 1.0 only.

You can try this workaround to get required output

```
//span[string-length(substring-before(substring-after(.,'PROVIDER_6'), '_')) = 2 and contains(@class, 'value')]
```

Explanation:

- `substring-after(.,'PROVIDER_6')` return substring after `"PROVIDER_6"` from nodes with text representation that starts with `"PROVIDER_6"`:

  `"PROVIDER_628_54678931"` --> `"28_54678931"`
- `substring-before(<STRING>, '_')` extracts substring before `"_"`:

  `"28_54678931"` --> `"28"`
- `string-length(<STRING>) = 2` checks if string length exactly equal to `2`:

  string length of `"28"` is equal to `2`

So in your case XPath will "ignore" `"PROVIDER_730_54678933"` as it doesn't start with `"PROVIDER_6"` and `"PROVIDER_6542_54678934"` as string length of `"542"` is equal to `3`, but not `2`

Comment: The only what worked, TY